# Create calendar Event in Google App maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm really a beginner with Appmaker. How can I create events from a specific calendar instead of the default calendar?  I've try several thing but I need little help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google posted some example code for the Advanced Calendar Service in Apps Script [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-samples/blob/master/advanced/calendar.gs). It looks like it lists out the user's calendars, and then you can select a Calendar ID to create the event on. [image]

Remember that you'll need to turn on the Advanced Calendar service in your App's settings.